# Conditional statement only displaying information if it is different from last record - PHP - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

i have a table full of data in the form of

value_id value_name value_timestamp

The first 5 columns have the same value name (with different id's and timestamps)

how would i go about producing a conditional statement that went through and only displayed the first name with the same value. Ie i only want to show row 1, not 5 rows. then i want to display the 6th row's name as its different

Ive had a go but with no luck -

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Films_Info") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
$name = $row['value_name'];  
if ("same as previous"($name)) {
    echo $name;
    }
    else 
    {
     //do nothing 
     }

}
```

Thanks guys

Table results -

```
film_id   film_name   film_date
1         example     Thursday
2         example1    Thursday
3         example3    Thursday
4         example4    Friday
```

So i want to display film_id 1 and its date, but skip 2 and 3 (film_id) as there the same, then display example 4.

Comment: Also, `$film_desc` isn't declared anywhere in this code, so it will always result in the "else" block.

Comment: I might of got slightly confused but i want to - check if previous entry in database is the same, if it is don't echo out anything but still keep on going through

Comment: Please provide table data examples with desired results.

Comment: Why would you want to skip those? They're not the same.

Comment: skip them because the date is the same i meant

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10354/discussion-between-dim3nsion-and-blake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your sql statement to be specific.

`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Films_Info WHERE name='{$name}'") or die(mysql_error());`

UPDATE: After some chat discussion, this is what you should do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $grouping = $row['film_date'];  
    $movies[$grouping][] = $row
}
```

This will group your same-date movies into an array for you to manipulate.

Comment: ideally i want to cycle through them as grouping will disrupt there order. For instance i want to show the first film on that day and not the rest. Might of worded my question wrong :S

Answer (score 0):

don't know how much this will help but what I have done in the past is create a temporary mysql table formatted exactly the same as the previous table that has the data, then used a SELECT *FROM temptable WHERE condition = preferredCondition

then after the code was used ran a 
DROP TABLE temptable command deleting the table itself.

Comment: Why would you do that, out of pure curiosity?

Comment: to be honest, I tried to loop through the output of a sql statement in my own code and if the results had a different id or whatnot it simply wouldn't loop through, what I ended up doing was creating an id field with all of my tables and when I needed to copy them I created a new temporary table and to loop through them I made iteration counter that was equivelent to the then post number

Comment: Usually if something is that complicated, you're doing it wrong :( I've -never- had to use temporary tables in my nearly 15 years experience with programming / databasing.

Comment: so for example in the new table that was created with the WHILE mysql statement, it would be a simple matter of an iteration while loop that compares to the row number ran through with a mysql_num_rows command

Comment: just out of curiosity, how would you do a query without the iteration statement? I have only been using sql with php for the last 3 weeks and never did mysql previously/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not even sure what you mean by that last post. I've been desperately trying to figure it out, though.

Comment: let me show you some of the code, I am probably doing it horribly wrong and for whoever will look at my code I appologize

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10355/discussion-between-blake-and-justin-michael-gooch)

Comment: Join me in chat and be my guest.

Comment: //create table
//copy query from original table into new table
//count mysql number of rows with mysql_num_row
//create iteration count variable and declare as 1
//create while statement while iteration count <= mysql_num_rows
//print out row while id = iteration_count